# Extract a substring in R with no pattern

Tags: r

If one of my strings in a column looks like,

```
string = "P/project/dhi_intro_genomics/genomics/gene/pag-files-per-patient/000tg82e-99c4-4h20-9ude-d95e15005a 3c_KXgES5FtCpLhQce7mGkuMX/XML/JH_DN_S9_2000-12-27_MTW-29FEB1997UW"
```

Is there a str_extract code to get

```
sub_string = "000tg82e-99c4-4h20-9ude-d95e15005a 3c"
```

from the original 'string'?

Comment: What does "no pattern" mean?

Comment: We'll need more detail before anyone can try to answer this. You're asking, "ow can I get values "foo" from a string, but you could simply do this as `result <- "foo"` so presumably there is a more general and precise question of how to get certain types of strings meeting certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the pattern to get the substring that are not a `_` character after the `patient/` substring

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "(?<=patient\\/)0+[^_]+")
[1] "000tg82e-99c4-4h20-9ude-d95e15005a 3c"
```

---

If there are no pattern and wants to extract the 7th element based on delimiter `/`

```
 trimws(strsplit(string, "/")[[1]][7], whitespace = "_.*")
[1] "000tg82e-99c4-4h20-9ude-d95e15005a 3c"
```

Or with `str_replace`

```
str_replace(string, "([^/]+/){6}([^_]+)_.*", "\\2")
[1] "000tg82e-99c4-4h20-9ude-d95e15005a 3c"
```

---

For the new string

```
str_new <- c("/P/project/dlf_intro_aion/Y0793/Y0793_8665030498_T1_K1IJ2_ps20200918125614.htj.gz.pd5", 
"/P/project/dlf_intro_aion/H051/H0518946_032983_T1_K1ID2_ps20289239171246.par.gz"
)
str_replace(str_new, "^/?([^/]+/){4}[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*", "\\2")
[1] "8665030498" "032983"
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. May I know how to extract substring if **patient/** is not present?

Comment: @pkavuri perhaps the update helps

Comment: Thank you for the response. May I know how to extract substring if the patient/ is not present? Example: If I have 2 different strings under same column like string1 = "/P/project/dlf_intro_aion/Y0793/Y0793_**8665**_030498_T1_K1IJ2_ps20200918125614.htj.gz.pd5",  and string2 = "/P/project/dlf_intro_aion/H051/H051_**8946**_032983_T1_K1ID2_ps20289239171246.par.gz". How to get the bold segments from string1, and 2?

Comment: @pkavuri in the new case, your extraction substring is different because in the original question you are extracting a long sequence of characters i.e. are you looking for only `8665` and `8946` values?

Comment: Apologies for wrong bolded values. I want to extract '8665030498' from string1 and '032983' from string2.

Comment: It is not clear from the bolded values. Because your original question was to extract something altogher different

Comment: @pkavuri you have different requrirement here.  I updated